# HTML Element Scrollbar positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently making some improvements on a website and ran into the following issue.

The website has a sticky / fixed header, thus only the body is scrollable.

One of the pages has a large data table which expands to a width of over 1000px and the height could also be quite high depending on the date selection for data.

Now my problem is that the scrolling is enabled on the div that wraps the table, but you have to scroll all the way to the bottom to see the scrollbar.

What I would like to know, is there some way that I can move the horizontal scrollbar, with javascript or css, to my website's footer, as this element is always visible to the user?

Example:
[image]

Footer overlaps the table, thus you have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to see the horizontal scrollbar. I would like to move the horizontal scrollbar of the wide table to my sites footer where it is always visible. The table wrapper and footer is not nested within each other.

Sample Code I am currently using (HTML):

```
<div class="wmd-view-topscroll">
    <div class="scroll-div">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wmd-view">
    <div class="dynamic-div">
<table class="results table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="table-layout: fixed; width:1750px;">
<!-- Contents here -->
</table>
</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Sample Code I am currently using (jQuery):

```
$(function () {

    $(".wmd-view-topscroll").scroll(function () {
        $(".wmd-view")
        .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view-topscroll").scrollLeft());
    });

    $(".wmd-view").scroll(function () {
        $(".wmd-view-topscroll")
        .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wmd-view-topscroll").prependTo($("#siteFooter"));
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('.scroll-div').css('width', $('.dynamic-div').outerWidth() );
});
```

The above code basically creates a clone of the scrollbar, then I grab that HTML and appendTo my footer, which works, but now I still have the scrollbar on my main table wrapper.

When you scroll all the way to the bottom you see 2x scrollbars. The one I placed in my footer plus the one from the main table wrapper. If I try and make changes to the `.wmd-view` overflow properties, it also changes the one in my footer.

Any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the link of site.

Comment: Hi @Leothelion , unfortunately this is not a publicly accessible website :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `height` for `.dynamic-div` and give `overflow: auto`

Comment: Hi @afelixj ,this just causes another scrollbar to appear, because these properties have been set on `.wmd-view`